# AngularJS Filter (onclick) with Multiple Filter Values

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to filter by filter1 AND filter2 AND filter3. Everything works except for my ng-click attributes. I'm not clear on how the syntax should look to make this example function as needed.

Here is a link to the example: http://jsfiddle.net/40vrs6db/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MainController">
<div ng-repeat="strain in strainsFound = (strains | filter:{name: strain_name, storesThatHaveIt:strain_storesThatHaveIt, tod:strain_tod})">
    <div>
        <p data-t="{{strain.storesThatHaveIt}}">{{strain.name}}</p>
        <p>{{strain.tod}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<select ng-model="strain_tod">
    <option value="morning">Morning</option>
    <option value="afternoon">Afternoon</option>
    <option value="evening">Evening</option>
    <option value="night">Night</option>

</select>
<div ng-model="strain_storesThatHaveIt">
    <a ng-click="Hastings">Hastings</a>
    <a ng-click="Kingsway">Kingsway</a>
    <a ng-click="Quebec">Quebec</a>
    <a ng-click="Ontario">Ontario</a>

</div>
<input ng-model="strain_name" />
</div>


function MainController($scope) {

$scope.strain_name = "";
$scope.strain_storesThatHaveIt = "";
$scope.strain_tod = "";

$scope.strains = [{
    "storesThatHaveIt": ["Hastings", "Ontario", "Kingsway"],
        "name": "rub",
        "tod": ["night"]
}, {
    "storesThatHaveIt": ["Hastings"],
        "name": "shatter",
        "tod": ["evening", "night"]
}, {
    "storesThatHaveIt": ["Kingsway"],
        "name": "sour diesel",

        "tod": ["morning", "afternoon", "evening"]
}, {
    "storesThatHaveIt": ["Hastings", "Quebec"],
        "name": "m39",
        "tod": ["morning", "afternoon"]
}]
```

}

Comment: Well if you open the console you will see where your mistake is.

Comment: I did, I do not see a single error. BTW this is the first angular script I've ever written.

Comment: What do you want to do with ng-click i don't understand your goal, can you explain me ?

Comment: when I click on an ng-click for example "Hastings" I want only the hastings locations to show. However I'm using this filter in conjunction with the other filters in the code (the dropdown and input box).

So if I filter using the input box it will display less results, then I want the ng-click to further narrow down the result set.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kvsku0fd/3/ smth like this mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Petr Averyanov I now have the answer :

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MainController">
<div ng-repeat="strain in strainsFound = (strains | filter:{name: strain_name, storesThatHaveIt:strain_storesThatHaveIt, tod:strain_tod})">
    <div>
        <p data-t="{{strain.storesThatHaveIt}}">{{strain.name}}</p>
        <p data-t="{{strain.storesThatHaveIt}}">{{strain.tod}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<select ng-model="strain_tod">
    <option value="morning">Morning</option>
    <option value="afternoon">Afternoon</option>
    <option value="evening">Evening</option>
    <option value="night">Night</option>

</select>
<div>
    <a ng-click="strain_storesThatHaveIt = 'Hastings'">Hastings</a>
    <a ng-click="strain_storesThatHaveIt = 'Kingsway'">Kingsway</a>
    <a ng-click="strain_storesThatHaveIt = 'Quebec'">Quebec</a>
    <a ng-click="strain_storesThatHaveIt = 'Ontario'">Ontario</a>

</div>
<input ng-model="strain_name" />
</div>

<script>
function MainController($scope) {

    $scope.strain_name = "";
    $scope.strain_storesThatHaveIt = "";
    $scope.strain_tod = "";

    $scope.strains = [{
        "storesThatHaveIt": ["Hastings", "Ontario", "Kingsway"],
        "name": "rub",
        "tod": ["night"]
    }, {
        "storesThatHaveIt": ["Hastings"],
        "name": "shatter",
        "tod": ["evening", "night"]
    }, {
        "storesThatHaveIt": ["Kingsway"],
        "name": "sour diesel",
        "tod": ["morning", "afternoon", "evening"]
    }, {
        "storesThatHaveIt": ["Hastings", "Quebec"],
        "name": "m39",
        "tod": ["morning", "afternoon"]
    }]
}
</script>
```